# Rspec argumenterror when passing invalid parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm creating an Rspec controller test for a create action that takes parameters for two objects, story and ku.  Story validates presence of title and large_cover_url.  Not sure why rspec throws an argument error when passing invalid parameters, and could use some insight on this issue.

Here is the error:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, story: {title: nil, large_cover_url: "present"}, ku: Fabricate.attributes_for(:ku)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
     # ./app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:18:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/stories_controller_spec.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the spec:

```
context "failed story creation" do
    let(:bob) { Fabricate(:user) }
    before { sign_in_user(bob) }

    it "does not create a new story" do
        post :create, story: {title: nil, large_cover_url: "present"}, ku: Fabricate.attributes_for(:ku)
        expect(Story.count).to eq(0)
    end
end
```

Here is the controller action:

```
def create
    @story = Story.new(params[:story])
    @ku = Ku.new(params[:ku])
  if @story.save && @ku.save
    @story.update_column(:user_id, current_user.id)
    @ku.update_column(:user_id, current_user.id)
    @story.kus << @ku
    redirect_to story_path(@story), flash: {success: "Your story was published."}
  else
    flash[:error] = "#{@story.errors.full_message.join(', ')}"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `full_message` accepts as parameters the name of an attribute an the error string, so when you do `flash[:error] = "#{@story.errors.full_message.join(', ')}"`, you are calling `full_message` without any parameters.
You should use `full_messages` instead that returns an array with all the error messages.

[ActiveModel::Errors api ref](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message)

Comment: Thank you Pablo, that was spot on!